# PHP Caracter ´ ñ PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql

Mi profe me paso este codigo en PDO para un box dinamico que carga una lista en la db, pues esta tiene caracteres especiales. Mi pregunta es donde inserto el utf8_encode() para que puedan salir bien los caracteres?.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','web');
if(!$db) {
    echo 'ERROR: no se pudo conectar a base de datos';
} else {
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE (nombre LIKE '%$queryString%' or id LIKE '%$queryString%' )");
            if($query) {
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    echo '<li value="'.$result->id. '" onClick="fill(\''.$result->nombre. ' ' .$result->tipo.'\');">'.$result->nombre. ' ' .$result->tipo.'</li>';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: no se pudo realizar la consulta';
            }
        } else {
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Sin datos disponibles';
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Realmente te tocaría utilizar  utf8_decode()   porque el caracter lo extraes de la base de datos. El `utf8_encode()` se utiliza antes de ingresarlo a la base de datos. Respondí una pregunta muy similar hace poco. Espero sea de ayuda para tí: [mostrar caracteres especiales correctamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/127682/mostrar-correctamente-caracteres-codificados-del-estilo-xe9/127695#127695)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El utf8_encode iria donde llames al valor UTF8 en este caso $result->nombre

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','web');
if(!$db) {
    echo 'ERROR: no se pudo conectar a base de datos';
} else {
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE (nombre LIKE '%$queryString%' or id LIKE '%$queryString%' )");
            if($query) {
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    echo '<li value="'.$result->id. '" onClick="fill(\''.utf8_encode($result->nombre). ' ' .$result->tipo.'\');">'.utf8_encode($result->nombre). ' ' .$result->tipo.'</li>';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: no se pudo realizar la consulta';
            }
        } else {
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Sin datos disponibles';
    }
}
?>
```