# Error de codificación con UTF-8 en angular

Tags: angular

Estoy configurando el index.html en angular de la siguiente forma:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Parameter</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <base href="/"> 
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Sin embargo los caracteres con acentos no son visualizados, ¿Alguna idea de qué pueda ser, o qué configuración adicional deba realizar en angular?

```
<div class="form-group row text-center">
            <label for="inputSMinimo"
                class="col-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-7 col-form-label">Saldo
                mínimo</label> <input type="number"
                class="form-control col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"
                id="inputSMinimo" [(ngModel)]="parameters[3].value"
                placeholder="Ingrese valor" [disabled]="inputStatus" required
                name="inputSMinimo">
        </div>
```

[image: Así se imprime]

Comment: Hace un tiempo respondí una pregunta similar. Puede que te ayude el siguiente enlace [Mostrar correctamente caracteres codificados del estilo \xe9](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/127682/mostrar-correctamente-caracteres-codificados-del-estilo-xe9/127695#127695) y también puedes visitar este otro enlace [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base). Un saludo

Comment: Verificaste que las respuesta de tú servicio sean correctas, tal vez el problema de codificación se encuentra ahí.

Comment: El error se genera en un html básico. Sin consultas a la bd. Veo que ese charset, no se carga en el componente html, ya que donde lo declaro sí puedo usar tildes. Alguna idea?

Comment: Por alguna razón los archivos no estaban leyendo el index.html global, así que tuve que poner el meta en cada archivo html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perdón por abrir una respuesta pero no tengo los puntos para comentar, veo que ya tienes una etiqueta meta, podrías intentar agregar esta en tu

**index.html**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Dentro del meta, ya se encuentra esta configuración